# python lib to detect blur image

Tags: python, image, blur

Does anyone know the last techniques to detect a blur image in python (or any other lib/app) ?

Actually I use ffmpeg to extract frames from videos. 
The idea is to check these extracted frames and remove the blured ones.

Comment: You may be interested in: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you talking about `motion blur` or `unsharp region`

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late for the person asking this question.
I found a link here that can detected the amount of blur in the image.

By using OpenCV, Python, and the Laplacian operator.

[Blur detection with OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/)

Might be of some use to others

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any lib that does that, but I'd suggest you to look at [Image gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient) . Since blur images doesn't have "edges", the sum of the values of the gradient of a blur image  is lower than the image gradient of the same non-blur image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and worked quite well. Not perfect but pretty well.
https://gist.github.com/shahriman/3289170